# Nginx redirect www.X.domain.com subdomain

Tags: regex, ubuntu, nginx

I would want to redirect www.X.domain.com to www.domain.com/.../X  .  So far I managed to redirect  X.domain.com to www.domain.com/../X .  Below the nginx configuration I tried.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#does not work (www.X.domain.com)                                                                                                                                  
server {                                                                                                                                        
    server_name www\.(?<subdomain>)\.domain\.com$;                                                                                           

    location / {                                                                                                                                
        rewrite ^ $scheme://www.domain.com/somedir/$subdomain;                                                                             
   }                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                               

#works (X.domain.com)                                                                                                                                         
server {                                                                                                                                        
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.domain\.com$;                                                                                           

    location / {                                                                                                                                
        rewrite ^ $scheme://www.domain.com/somedir/$subdomain;                                                                             
   }                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss `\w+` and `~` correct part is

```
server {                                                                                                                                        
  server_name "~^www\.(?<subdomain>\w+)\.domain\.com$";                                                                                           

  location / {                                                                                                                                
      rewrite ^ $scheme://www.domain.com/somedir/$subdomain;                                                                             
  }                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Comment: Apologies for never have responded but thx, that did the trick!